# $e^y = x-r$ , $r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ has one real root only and state the range of $r$.

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, roots, graphing-functions

Now given that $e^y = x-r$ , $r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ has one real root only and state the range of $r$.

For a start $y = \ln(x-r)$ and hence the root of it should be $x = r+1$. How should I deduce the answer $r \geq 2?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $r\in\mathbb Z^+=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$, $$x=(r+1)\in\{2,3,4,\cdots\}$$

---

If the question is asking for what value of $r$ does the equation $e^y=x-r$ has one unique real root, then clearly the answer is all $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hi I edited the question cause it was asking the range of $r$ which is $\geq 2$ which is weird.